# Arabic text displays as question marks - firebase hosting

Tags: html, firebase-hosting, arabic-support

I'm setting up a page for terms with firebase hosting. I deployed the page but my text in page shows as question marks. my text is in Arabic language.
I tried many answers, but none of them work.

maybe the problem in firebase hosting?

I tried:

```
- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

- <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1256"> 

- <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-6">
```

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<body>
<h1 dir='rtl' lang='ar' >الشروط</h1>
<p dir="rtl" lang="ar">الشروط</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code looks OK - just make sure your editor save it in UTF-8,
To verify this - download the file from the server as "yourfilename.html" and open it locally in your browser - see if you see it in Arabic.
If you don't, open it in notepad - you will probably see question marks which means you didn't save the file in UTF-8 format - you probably saved it as ASCII.
If on the other hand you will see it in Arabic - seek in the response structure you receive maybe something there is not right.

Comment: I opened the file in my browser with this line (<meta charset="utf-8"/>), the result same text shows as question marks, but when i changed brivuse line to this (<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">) its work good in my locally browser but when i deploy it to firebase hosting the problem still